# Were short stem coupe glasses common in the 1920's?

Tags: fashion, modern, 1920s

Please advise, if I am mixing something up horribly.

I remember images I've *occasionally* seen several times over past 30 years -- either historical posters or illustrations, maybe even  American/European vintage fashion photos, -- with women holding very short stemmed champagne glasses ([coupes](https://www.etsy.com/listing/1158977179/pair-of-short-stem-champagne-coupes)), and holding them not by the stem, but cupped in hand. The dating of the images were what I believe (by their hair and dresses) ~1920ies fashion (as described and shown, for example, [here](https://irrhoplaceable.blogspot.com/2013/04/1920s-fashion.html)).

Now, the curious thing is that I started looking into these antique short-stemmed champagne coupes and I can't find even a single *image* with anything remotely similar (not to talk about anything like that being sold online, on either general or antique sites.

The only thing I can find are medium or long-stemmed glasses. I realize holding a glass by stem made and makes more sense as it reduces the heat from hand going to the glass, but there is a very vivid recollection of the short-stemmed ones, so short that as the person cups the glass in their hand, there may be no stem visible. Something quite similar (except much more delicate and graceful) to some kind of [desert bowl](https://you.com/proxy?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftse2.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.QwvSDITde-P5fGkKQ68NuwHaFi%26w%3D690%26c%3D7%26pid%3DApi%26p%3D0).

So I've started to wonder, were short stem coupe glasses a thing at all at around start of 20th century, or is my mind is playing tricks on me?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: @mcw Updated to include the question in proper form

Comment: @mcw you should make this a response, not a comment.

Comment: Just a memory from the 1970s that could be related: I remember short stemmed wine cups and water cups (or wine cups used to serve water to children on holidays). Some of them nearly didn't have a stem at all. The ones I remember were similar to the shortest ones from https://www.remodelista.com/posts/10-easy-pieces-squat-wine-glasses/ . However they weren't for Champagne, as the Champagne cups my family used had a long stem (although the cups were wide and short instead of long and thin as nowadays).

Answer (score -1):

[Food52](https://food52.com/blog/12220-from-cup-to-coupe-a-history-of-our-favorite-champagne-glass) confirms your memory,

> "It was, after all, the Champagne vessel of choice for ‘20s flappers, and Hollywood leading ladies from Marilyn Monroe to Sophia Loren were frequently photographed imbibing from a coupe in their heydays."

Comment: This source seems to be discussing coupe glasses in general, not addressing the *short-stemmed* variety the question seems to want to focus on. An example can be seen [here](https://www.etsy.com/listing/1158977179/pair-of-short-stem-champagne-coupes).

Comment: [Some examples](https://www.etsy.com/listing/1261532827/champagne-glasses-crystal-chiseled?click_key=94ab42fd2336dd1878b1229696865fe89aafec2a%3A1261532827&click_sum=ae1092be&ref=sold_out-2) of this type of glass do seem to be dated to the 1920s however.

Comment: That's one of the reasons I asked for a definition - since I don't drink champagne, I didn't understand the distinction.  It can be challenging to answer a question where OP has lots of contextual knowledge that isn't present in the question. I've edited one of your images into the original question - can you edit further to clarify?

Comment: If the OP is misremembering the nature of the glasses, then almost any period-piece movie such as the Great Gatsby(pick your version) will show flappers cradling champaign coupes...